# $ \{X_n\mathbb{1}_{X_n\in[-n,n]}\}$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, integration

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables satisfying :
$$
\sup_{n}{\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)} <\infty
$$
Suppose that
$$
\dfrac{M_j}{2}<\int_{j-1<|X_{n}|\leq j}{|X_{n}(t)|d\mathbb{P}(t)}\leq M_j+\dfrac{1}{j^2} \qquad\forall n\geq 1 \text{ and }1\leq j\leq n^2
$$
with $M_j>0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{M_j}<\infty$.

Show that:
$$
 \{X_n\mathbb{1}_{X_n\in[-n,n]}\}\text{ is uniformly integrable} 
$$

Any ideas, please?

Comment: This is sequel to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357070/lemma-of-x-n-is-a-sequence-of-random-variables-satisfying-sup-n-m The introduction of $\frac{1}{j^2}$ is completely superfluous. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $K, n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $K<n$ we have that
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|X_n|1_{X_n\in[-n, n]}1_{|X_n|>K}] &= \mathbb{E}[|X_n|1_{n \geq |X_n|>K}]\\
&=\int_{n\geq |X_n|>K} |X_n|d\mathbb{P}\\
&= \sum_{j=K+1}^n \int_{j\geq |X_n|>j-1} |X_n|d\mathbb{P}\\
&\leq \sum_{j=K+1}^n M_j+1/j^2\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty M_j\right)+ \left(\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty 1/j^2\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Note that the final bound does not depend on $n$, so $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[|X_n|1_{X_n\in[-n, n]}1_{|X_n|>K}]\leq \left(\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty M_j\right)+ \left(\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty 1/j^2\right)\overset{K\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Hence, we have uniform integrability.